# Google map responsive cut address issue

Tags: google-maps

I have embedded an google responsive map on my "Contact us" page. Now issue is that my address is not visible completely because it got cropped from top.

Here is my code:

[`jsFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/67eaebyg/)

Please see below screen-short, with address cropped from top.
[image]

Please guide me.

Comment: haven't get your question.. please describe more..

Comment: Where's your code? jsfiddle link you share is image @@

Comment: Actully I am looking for create responsive google map with see full content(Company name at top, address, phone etc..),You can see onces I try to load my page my company name hide at top screen. its directly start with address, Once I move camera my company name visible.

Thanks,

Comment: Sorry here is my fiddle link.
http://jsfiddle.net/67eaebyg/4/

Comment: Here is my latest code .. http://jsfiddle.net/67eaebyg/6/

Comment: Thank you so much for quick reply..

Comment: Excuse me, bro, your fiddle not shown your issue in result? It shows a blank page

Comment: I had updated with jquery library, and it could show Company name: Techacorn. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/67eaebyg/7/). In my opinion, your issue  could be Google map location deviations with your `center`

Comment: Thank you so much you have just saved my time...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87759/discussion-between-mr-neo-and-roni).